# Как инсталлировать и запустить Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor на Windows 7?

Tags: android, windows-7, эмулятор

Мучаюсь с установкой Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD. Студия установилась, но при создании эмуляции смартфона видно, что нужно инсталлировать этот никак не инсталлирующийся драйвер -
[image: не инсталлируется драйвер]

хотя в панели SDK я его инсталлировал и в папке extras\google этот пак инсталлирован без проблем. А вот проблемы начинаются - когда пробую его инсталлировать по советам опытных, перерыв весь гугл и этот форум. Хоть в Андроид Студио, хоть в панели командной строки - почему то не срабатывает команда "silent_install.bat" результат на фото -
[image: не срабатывает правильно команда "silent_install.bat"]
. В биосе смотрел - виртуализация включена (enabled). Что за чертовщина, кто знает? Получилось ли хоть у кого инсталлировать Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD на Windows 7?

Updated - после коммента скриншот с моим процессорм,
[image: параметры процессора]

там нет именно SSSE3 - в этом дело? Или все еще не найдено, почему драйвер не заработал?

Comment: У меня не устанавливается, но причину я знаю - процессор не поддерживает `SSSE3` (обязательное требование гипервизора) - проверьте, может ваш случай тоже.

Comment: А бъясните пожалуйста подробнее, что это за код и требования. Я насколько вычитывал инфо -  в АМД в биосе SVM support(виртуализацию) надо включить на enabled. Сделал, но... Обидно, что как в стену уперся с этим драйвером. Где же решение?

Answer (score 0):

Внимательней, SSE3 ваш процессор поддерживает, а SSSE3 нет, да дело именно этом программе для работы нужны микро-коды из пакета SSSE3, для AMD это процессоры с ядром Zambezi и Vishera (линйка fx), либо Zen на новой платформе